# transparent view with parent view in swift

Tags: swift

I have a MyView and top of MyView I have a Transparent View , When I click anywhere on the Transparent View I need to call a function, It is working fine but When I am clicking on the Transparent View where the MyView is the underneath , here my function is not calling ,

I need to call a function anywhere I click on the Transparent View .

Comment: Please add your code to show how did you create and add the `MyView` and `TransparentView` to your view hierarchy. We can suggest the best way to solve this by understanding your view hierarchy better.